# Google Analytics Management API - Insert method - invalid accountId HTTP 400

Tags: google-analytics

I am trying to add users to my Google Analytics account through the API but the code yields this error:
`invalid accountId: xxxxxx@gmail.com."`
Where I got account Id. Isn't It  mean for user's Email ?

Comment: AccountId is the id of the Google Analytics account.  User e-mail is wrapped  inside a userRef object.  See the examples here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/accountUserLinks/insert#examples

Comment: Why don't you show your code here?

Answer (score 0):

> [Account User Links: insert](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/accountUserLinks/insert) adds a new user to the given account if the user has fewer than 100 accounts.

Go to the admin section of the Google Analytics website.

[image]

You will find your account ID under basic Account settings.